# "Request had insufficient authentication scopes" from Spring boot application on GCE accessing Datastore

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a spring boot application which will run on Google Compute engine and will use Google Datastore.
When deploying this on GCE, I am getting "Request had insufficient authentication scopes." error while accessing Datastore

I have kept the value of `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location` blank. So app will pick up the default service account. I have also granted this service account datastore Owner role. There is a log line in the app (`Scopes in use by default credentials` `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore`) which confirms that this account has the datastore access

[image: gcp screenshot]

I want to ideally run this app using a service account & not use my personal google account for authentication.

Logs

````
2023-02-01 02:44:19.464  INFO 9595 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 451 ms. Found 1 Datastore repository interfaces.
2023-02-01 02:44:22.023  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-01 02:44:22.050  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-01 02:44:22.051  INFO 9595 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
2023-02-01 02:44:22.236  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-01 02:44:22.237  INFO 9595 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5903 ms
2023-02-01 02:44:23.117  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is XXX
2023-02-01 02:44:23.200  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for Google Compute Engine.
2023-02-01 02:44:23.200  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
2023-02-01 02:44:25.999 ERROR 9595 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
....
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at com.adrian.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:138) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:123) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:200) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:194) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:191) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105) ~[gax-1.60.1.jar!/:1.60.1]
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76) ~[google-cloud-core-1.94.0.jar!/:1.94.0]
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50) ~[google-cloud-core-1.94.0.jar!/:1.94.0]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:190) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:183) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:174) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.DatastoreTemplate.findAll(DatastoreTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.DatastoreTemplate.findAll(DatastoreTemplate.java:360) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.DatastoreTemplate.findAll(DatastoreTemplate.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository.support.SimpleDatastoreRepository.findAll(SimpleDatastoreRepository.java:122) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy65.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy65.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.adrian.demo.common.config.Config.postConstruct(Config.java:57) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:136) ~[datastore-v1-proto-client-1.6.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:185) ~[datastore-v1-proto-client-1.6.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:96) ~[datastore-v1-proto-client-1.6.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.runQuery(Datastore.java:119) ~[datastore-v1-proto-client-1.6.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:198) ~[google-cloud-datastore-1.105.3.jar!/:1.105.3]
        ... 77 common frames omitted```
````

Answer (score 0):

## The service account you're using for authentication has to have the correct access scope.

It must have a [Datastore access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#associating_a_service_account_to_an_instance) to connect into Cloud Datastore API. You may refer to this documentation [Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest).

Then you must set proper [authenticate workloads using service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#console_1) using the console in the VM details page.

**You must restart the instance after making changes to the authenticate workloads in order for them to take effect.**